# dynamically render the content into div element

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to render some content into div section which is in user control( 
Example.ascx) through code behind file(Example.ascx.cs),

Example.ascx

```
<div id="DivElement" runat="server">
</div>
```

Example.ascx.cs

```
void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.PreRender += new EventHandler(Ex_PreRender);
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

void Ex_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             this.DivElement.Load(@"<input type='hidden' name='{0}' id='{0}_VIEW' value='{2}' />
       <input type='hidden' name='{0}' value='{3}' />

                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                        $(document).ready(function() {{
                        _controllers['{0}'] = new ExController({{
                        id: '{0}',
                        src: '{1}',
                        }});
                       _controllers['{0}'].Load();
                         }});
                      </script>",
                        this.id,
                        this.src,
                        Request[this.id + "_VIEWSTATE"];);
        }
```

I tried like above but the content not load into the DivElement. Can anyone suggest how to render
the above elements into div?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a literal.

```
<div><asp:literal id="litContent" runat="server"></div>
```

Then in your code-behind, use:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    litContent.Text = "Your Content";
}
```

I also notice you have a few errors in your string.  If you want to insert strings into strings, you will need to use string.Format().

Here's an example:

```
litContent.Text = string.Format("hello {0}.  I am a {1}", "you", "test");
```

So, looking at your string, you will want to do something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = "fetchThisFromSomewhere";
    string src = "fetchThisToo";
    litContent.Text = string.Format(@"
            <input type='hidden' name='{0}' id='{0}_VIEW' value='{2}' />
            <input type='hidden' name='{0}' value='{3}' />

            <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function() {{
                _controllers['{0}'] = new ExController({{
                id: '{0}',
                src: '{1}',
                }});
                _controllers['{0}'].Load();
                    }});
                </script>",
                id,
                src,
                Request[id + "_VIEWSTATE"]);
}
```

Comment: Worked Fine. Thanks